# Adding multiple value to hidden field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden field in form A.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" />
```

I want to add multiple values to this field using jQuery on a button click. this value coming from pop up window that just add these values to hidden field .

```
var name = $('#formid input[name=name1]').val();  
$("#item_name").val(name);
```

suppose I added values two time "a" and "b"  then
when I submit the form and print the form values at server side. I get this value

```
["item_name"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(2) "ab"
}
```

how should I proceed to get these value like -

```
 ["item_name"]=>
 array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(1) "a",
 [1]=>
 string(1) "b"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks the button, you should append another hidden input to the form, with `name="item_name[]"` and the value you wish to add:

```
$('#formid input[name=name1]').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    $("#item_name").after(
        "<input name='item_name[]' value="+name+" />"
    );
});
```

This way, you can add several values instead of just two.
The loop in this case might be unnecessary (if you have just one element with name "name1"), but reflects the fact that you could use this with a selector returning more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 hidden inputs with the same name `item_name[]` for it to work like you want.

Or you can have something like this

```
if ($("#item_name").val() == '') {
    $("#item_name").val(name);
} else {
    var value = JSON.parse($("#item_name").val());
    $("#item_name").val(JSON.stringify(value.push(name)));
}
```

I haven't tested it but with JSON.stringify you could send an array in a single input.

Comment: Unexpected token aa.  "aa" is the value I entered when I followed your  second approach.